# ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock not working in Visual WebPart

Tags: javascript, c#

I am working in VisualWebPart and want to call Javascript method from c#. Below is my code. If I replace `myFunction();` with `alert()` then alert is working. However, `myFunction()` is not getting called. I tried with `ScriptManager.RegisterStartUpScript` too but fail. I debugged and there was no error too. Am I doing anything wrong?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
        alert('Function called successfully!');
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click"  />

c#
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction();", false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable the Script Tags while calling RegisterClientScriptBlock

Here is how:
.aspx.cs

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "myFunction", "myFunction();", true);
    }
```

.aspx

```
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function myFunction() {
            alert('Function called successfully!');
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

By providing "true" to the last parameter will make the script to add "Script" tags, then the function will be called accordingly with all validations.

[image: Alert Msg]

Comment: Hi Sai, I did but no message shown after button click.

Comment: @Chintan.Desai, where you have placed the script in .aspx page?  Place it under <head></head> tag and try it will work.

Comment: I am working in UserControl so can't define head and form tag since it has already been defined in Master page.

Comment: Anybody can help me out? I tried with ClientScriptManager too but no alert box is shown.

Comment: same problem, I think is framework 2.0 version that use SP2010